# Does Morphtronic Cameran defense effect negate trap and spell?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I wanna know if the effect in defense of the monster "Morphtronic Cameran" negate only effect of other monster or also trap and spell ?

Comment: Posting a link to the card text or spoiler might help someone answer faster. :)

Answer (score 2):

I may be answering this in a most "catch all" way, but I wanted to make sure how it works was clear to future readers who may misunderstand the card effect in this context.

The card text of Cameran reads:

> Morphtronic" monsters on the field cannot be targeted by effects.

This is a continuous effect [Card Rulings: Morphtronic Cameran](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Morphtronic_Cameran) that prevents all card effects from ***targeting*** Morphtronic monsters.

What this means is that it technically *does not* negate the card effects, it prevents Morphtronic monsters from being selected as targets from card effects that require choosing a card as a target.

Effects from cards like Dark Hole still apply and will destroy all the Morphtronic monsters because Dark Hole's effect does not select targets.

Effects that target will resolve something like so:

If a player chose to play *Compulsory Evacuation Device* (target one monster to return to the hand [CED](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Compulsory_Evacuation_Device)) when he/she controls one monster and the opponent has a Cameran in defense position and another Morphtronic monster, the player cannot select either of the opponent's monsters as targets, therefore he/she *must* return his/her own monster back to their hand.

Or in the instance that the player did not have that monster, they cannot activate the card because it does not have a legal target.

When it comes to resolving off of a chain: If a valid target was chosen (CED activated and Cameran was selected) and then it was no longer valid (i.e. a card was chained to CED's activation and the effect changed Cameran's position to defense before CED resolved), then in the resolution of CED nothing happens and CED goes to the graveyard because it is a normal trap card.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ["card effect"](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Effect) in YGO refers to the effect text of any type of cards.